# kind of iterator_to_array for a recursive iterator to get a bi-dimensional array

Tags: php, oop, iterator, spl

when using iterators in PHP you can use `iterator_to_array` function to kind of extract the array resulting of iterating. For example, let's say you have following `ArrayObject`:

```
$array_object = new ArrayObject(array(
   array('1', '2', '3', '4'),
   array('5', '6', '7', '8'),
   array('9', '10', '11', '12'),
));
```

As you see, its storage is a bi-dimensional array.

We can crete a `FilterOperator` to only accept its first item (I know it would be better with `LimitIterator`, it's just as an example purpose):

```
class myFilterIterator extends FilterIterator
{
   public function accept()
   {
      return ($this->key() === 0);
   }
}

$filter_iterator = new myFilterIterator(new ArrayIterator($array_object));
```

Now, if i do:

```
print_r(iterator_to_array($filter_iterator));
```

I get the array I could get if I manually loop through the operator:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) )
```

But what now if I want to work with a `RecursiveFilterIterator`? Let's say I have:

```
class myRecursiveFilterIterator extends RecursiveFilterIterator
{
   public function accept()
   {
      return ($this->hasChildren() || $this->key() === 0);
   }
}

$recursive_filter_iterator = new myRecursiveFilterIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array_object));
```

As you see, this will accept only key 0 for each array contained in the parent array. And so it works if I recursive iterate over it:

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursive_filter_iterator) as $value) {
   print_r($value);
   echo '<br />';
}
```

Results in:

```
1
5
9
```

But, how could I get quickly the array `array(array(1), array(5), array(9))` ?

If I do:

```
print_r(iterator_to_array($recursive_filter_iterator));
```

or

```
print_r(iterator_to_array($recursive_filter_iterator->getInnerIterator()));
```

or

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursive_filter_iterator);
print_r(iterator_to_array($it->getInnerIterator()));
```

I get whole original array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 [3] => 8 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 10 [2] => 11 [3] => 12 ) )
```

If I do:

```
print_r(iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursive_filter_iterator)));
```

I get just first item:

```
Array ( [0] => 9 )
```

If I do:

```
print_r(iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursive_filter_iterator->getInnerIterator())));
```

I get last item in my parent array but with key 0:

```
Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 10 [2] => 11 [3] => 12 )
```

**What I need is to get the array:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 9 ) )
```

I know I can get it manually looping, but I want to know if there is a direct way, like in `iterator_to_array` for not recursive iterators. Sure there is something I don't understand about recursive iterators in PHP, but its documentation is really bad in this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: *"its documentation is really bad"* — any feedback on this topic is welcomed, send me an email (my username on SO, @php.net).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are really wanting to do, but the following takes a `RecursiveArrayIterator` (note: `ArrayObject` is *not* a recursive iterator) and uses `iterator_to_array()` to get the resulting array that you want.

```
class FirstOnlyRecursiveArrayIterator extends ParentIterator {
    public function __construct(RecursiveArrayIterator $it) {
         parent::__construct($it);
    }
    public function current() {
        $children = parent::current();
        return array_slice($children, 0, 1);
    }
}

$array_it = new RecursiveArrayIterator(array(
    array('1', '2', '3', '4'),
    array('5', '6', '7', '8'),
    array('9', '10', '11', '12'),
));

$filter_iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new FirstOnlyRecursiveArrayIterator($array_it),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
print_r(iterator_to_array($filter_iterator));
```

Comment: Ok, thank you @salathe. This really works. But I think it's quite strange, or at least I don't understand it too much. PHP documentation says that `ParentIterator` is `FilterIterator` extended to show only elements which have children. So I think its `accept()` method only determine if its current element has children. Having to overwrite `current()` method to filter and not `accept()` I think its not very clean. Furthermore, my example should work because I'm checking as well if current has a children, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need/want to use iterators? You could use php's built-in array_map() function which takes an array and a function and applies the specified function to each element in the array. So you could do:

```
<?php
function get_first($foo)
{ 
    return array_slice($foo, 0, 1); //slice the array right after the first element
}

$array_object = new ArrayObject(array(
     array('1', '2', '3', '4'),
     array('5', '6', '7', '8'),
     array('9', '10', '11', '12'),
));

$new_array = array_map("get_first", $array_object->getArrayCopy());
print_r($new_array);
?>
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
        )
)
```

I apologise if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes, I would like to achieve this but using iterators :) Thank you anyway, @csOlar

Answer (score 0):

OK. One easy way could be the following. It extends the ArrayIterator class and overrides the current() function to return the sliced array:

```
<?php
class FirstOnlyIterator extends ArrayIterator
{
    public function current()
    {
            $next = parent::current();
            return array_slice($next, 0, 1);
    }
}

$array_object = new ArrayObject(array(
     array('1', '2', '3', '4'),
     array('5', '6', '7', '8'),
     array('9', '10', '11', '12'),
));

$iterator = new FirstOnlyIterator($array_object);

print_r(iterator_to_array($iterator));
?>
```

Comment: Hey, yes, I know there is easy ways to achieve what I want, but what I'd like is to get that using recursive iterators. Thank you anyway.